# SSL Handshake with private key HSM in C#.Net

Tags: c#, ssl, private-key, handshake, hardware-security-module

I am developing an application in C# that requires to authenticate itself as client (mTLS and TLS 1.3). But the client private key is in HSM and cannot be extracted. Therefore, I need to find way to delegate signing operations to HSM during handshake. Can someone help in finding the right place to Hook custom code?

I find something related but does not provide more detail:
[How to AuthenticateAsServer when Certificate is in HSM and privateKey is not embeded in Certificate and PrivateKey is not extractable from HSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74195361/how-to-authenticateasserver-when-certificate-is-in-hsm-and-privatekey-is-not-emb)
and
[Read Certificate from hsm and bind its private key to it and save in X509Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272645/read-certificate-from-hsm-and-bind-its-private-key-to-it-and-save-in-x509store)

Comment: The right place to start is with the manufacturer of the HSM.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. The manufacturer has provided the APIs that could be used to perform private key operations but they do not have experience with .Net SSL stack to hook the code for handshake